# How to call methods from extended class in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

This is the first time i used inheritance in coffeescript.

I'm trying to call method from extended class, but method @create from window.StreamingStation gives me this.create is not a function

```
class window.BaseClass
  constructor: (options) ->
    @key = options['key']
    @content_id = null
    @rtapi = options['rtapi']
    @switch = $('input[name="activate_autodj"]')
    @setup()

class window.StreamingStation extends window.BaseClass
  constructor: (options) ->
    super

  list: () ->
    $.ajax
      url: @rtapi + '/api/StreamingStation/list'
      type: 'get'
      data:
        query:
          data:
            contentId: @content_id
          token: @key
      success: (data) ->
        console.log(data)
    return

  create: () ->
    alert 'fsafsa'
    return

class window.AutoDj extends window.StreamingStation

  constructor: (options) ->
    super

  setup: ->
    @bindings()
    @activateAutoDj()

  bindings: () ->
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapSwitch({size: 'mini'});

  activateAutoDj: () ->
    $('input[data-id]').on 'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', (event, state) ->
      @create()
      state = (state == true ? 1 : 0)
      @content_id = $(this).attr('data-id')
      $.ajax
        url: "/autodjs/#{@content_id}/activate_autodj"
        type: 'post'
        data: {state: state}
        async: true
        success: (data) ->
          if (data.error == 0)
          else
            @raiseSystemAlert(data.message)
        error: (data) ->
          @raiseSystemAlert('Unexpected error, Please try again.')

  raiseSystemAlert: (message) ->
    modal = $('#systemAlertModal')
    modal.find('.modal-body').html(message)
    modal.modal('show')
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Been a while since I did coffeescript, but at first glance it appears you're not binding to the `this` context in the `...'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch'...` event handler. Try using a fat arrow / hash rocket (`=>`) for the function. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @ is this

so @create() is equal to this.create()

Comment: That's right. But the event handler is being called "asynchronously", and its `this` context will not be the `this` of the `AutoDj` instance.

Comment: @PaulRichter your right! awesome. I will look for a workaround.

Comment: Cool. I'll put that as an answer then.

Comment: by instantiating @ as cls works

cls = @
$('input[data-id]').on 'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', (event, state) ->
  cls.create()

Comment: Right. With a closure, yeah that's definitely one way of doing it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be in the event handler function you've declared inside the `activateAutoDj` method:

```
$('input[data-id]').on 'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', (event, state) ->
```

Since you're using a thin / stabby arrow, the `this` context of the event handler will not be the `this` context of the `AutoDj` instance; it will in fact be whatever the caller decides it will be, which in this case will be the object that initiated the event, if I'm not mistaken.

One way to solve this is to force the event handler function to bind to the `this` context using the fat / hashrocket (`=>`) arrow instead.

Or another way, as you pointed out, is to use a closure to preserve the `this` context of the parent function. As you indicated, you would simply do something like:

```
cls = @ # preserving the `this` context
$('input[data-id]').on 'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', (event, state) -> 
  cls.create()
  # rest of function
```